# How to denormalize deep hierarchies?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, nosql

I’ve read quite a lot about Cassandra and the art of denormalization and materialization while writing the data.  I think I understand the concept, and it seems to make sense. However, I am having some trouble implementing it in scenarios where there is a deep hierarchical data structure.

Consider the contrived domain where

Owner 1:* Company
   Company 1:* Teams
   Team 1:* Players
   Players 1:* Equipment

We have tables for each of these entities, but we would also like to query quickly for equipment attributes by owner so it seems the thing to do is create a table (OwnerEquipment) that has the owner id and the equipment id as the primary key with the owner id as the partition key.   This makes sense, but what if the UX scenarios that add and edit equipment do not include the owner’s id as part of the working set?

Most of the denormalization examples I’ve encountered in my research are usually a single level parent-child or master-detail type use case.  It seems pretty reasonable that an updating client would have enough information about the immediate parent when updating the child to write the denormalized reverse index, but what if the data you would really like to denormalize by is several “joins” away?

This problem is compounded further in our example when we consider a Company is sold to a different Owner.  Assume that the desired behavior is for OwnerEquipment to reflect this change.  How should the code that writes this updated Company to the database handle the OwnerEquipment table updates?  Should it, knowing the ID of the old owner, try to update all the OwnerEquipment records for that owner?  This seems like a very un-Cassandra-y thing to do and also fraught with concurrency issues.  The problem gets worse as you move down the chain (Team to new Company, Player to new Team).  In these cases the “old owner” is not necessarily in the working set and would need to be read in order to be updated.

Are there some better ways to think about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> This makes sense, but what if the UX scenarios that add and edit equipment do not include the owner’s id as part of the working set?

Easy, pass the owner id along with equipment id to the UX. Owner id can be a hidden value not to be shown on the interface

> but what if the data you would really like to denormalize by is several “joins” away?

Create as many tables for different query use-cases

For multiple updates and denormalizations, you can look at the new materialized views feature. Read my blog: www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=1930

Comment: Thanks! My interpretation of your answer seems to hint that all the tables would need to have the owner_id so that the Equipment table could have the owner_id, is that where this is going?

Comment: Not **all** table should have owner_id. Just put owner_id in the primary key where you need it for **query**

Comment: I guess this seems a little easier said than done.  Consider the scenario I mentioned where a company is changing owners.  There is an owner_id in the Company table and I'm updating it.  The only other place I care about owners is in my OwnerEquipment table.  But to update that table I need to read the Team and Player tables to get the list of Equipment to update.  Does that sound right?   This is the point where I think I'm doing it wrong because this is basically a join.  I'm just doing it on the update instead of the read.